# SQL error with inserting values into new table

Tags: sql

[Can someone advise me on the issue here? I've created the table named products but I can't seem to insert values into it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIGzd.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query window might not be pointing to the correct catalog. There must be a combobox somwhere (not showing in the image you provided) where you can check.

Or you can put at the begining of your query the following:

USE MVP_DB;

So that the query window will send the comands to this catalog.

Comment: Thank you sir, I've gotten this fixed! It works

Answer (score 0):

You're probably inside a different database. Have you tried

MVP_DB.dbo.Products

You should either click on the MVP_DB database and select new query or use the above

Comment: Thank you sir, I've managed to fixed it yesterday, you were right